# Is there a custom URL scheme for the built-in Contacts app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

I am trying to write an app that does a person search of my company. When it returns a result, I want to include a feature to add the person to the Contacts app with the push of a button.

The problem is, I can't find a way to launch the Contacts app through a custom URL scheme with the new person info as parameters.  Does anyone have any idea if this is possible and if so, how to go about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there were a public URL scheme, Apple would have documented it in the [URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Your options are:

1. [`ABNewPersonViewController` or `ABUnknownPersonViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbookui)
2. [Direct modification of the address book](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abaddressbook). ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100906215947/http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html))

Comment: Broken links :(

Answer (score 4):

There is a URL scheme for the Contacts app on the Mac – [the `addressbook` scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/URLScheme.html). You might want to try whether this works on iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

No,Not possible to open Default contact application as URL scheme is not available