# open contacts app form iPhone application

Tags: iphone, url, contacts, addressbook

I would like to open contacts app form iPhone application,

I have found reference to open the same using the following

ABNewPersonViewController or ABUnknownPersonViewController

but this is not in my case.

I need to open "Contacts" from a URL scheme, but no URL scheme available for it.

Please help me on the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531585/ios-custom-url-scheme-for-contacts-app

Comment: Yes, Bogatyr this is closely related but the same does nt have good solution. can you let me know if you have any solution?