# Is possible to open Contacts app from my app iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I wanted to know if it was possible to open the contacts app from my app iOS 7.
I'll explain,I would like to give the user the option of searching through contacts and then clicking on the contact to be redirected to contacts app with the specific page for the selected contact
Is possible?
And is possible also do this with reminders and calendar events?

Comment: You can open any app in iOS using custom scheme. Just search for open Contacts programatically..

Comment: Please show me how do this

Comment: The quick answer is, no, there does not appear to be a custom url scheme for opening `contacts.app` programatically. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531585/is-there-a-custom-url-scheme-for-the-built-in-contacts-app - which is, pretty much, a duplicate of this question

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, here is an example:

.h file:

```
@interface PickViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker;
@end
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    _peoplePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController:self.peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Delegate

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"Name %@", name);
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The question is about opening the Contacts app from within the application, not about accessing the contacts within the app

Answer (score -2):

- Add AddressBook Frame work.

  import AddressBook/AddressBook.h

Then I have a working example: You have to change the code in accordance to your requirements:

```
-(void)loadContact
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if (loadingView == nil) {
            loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInSuperView:self.view];
        }
    });
ABAddressBookRef ab;
ab = ABAddressBookCreate();


int len = (int) ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(ab);
NSMutableArray *allPeople = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < len ; i++)
{

    // Initialize the dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *dictAddress = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)([allPeople objectAtIndex:i]);

    [dictAddress setValue:@"0" forKey:@"sel"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"LastName"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"Name"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"PhoneMobile"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"PhoneHome"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"PhoneWork"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"CompanyName"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressCity"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressCountry"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressState"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressCountryCode"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressStreet"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"AddressZipCode"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"EmailWork"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"EmailHome"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"EmailOther"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"URLWork"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"URLHome"];
    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"URLOther"];

    [dictAddress setValue:@"" forKey:@"Note"];

    NSMutableString *xmlString = [NSMutableString string];

    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != NULL)
    {
        [dictAddress setValue:(NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)) forKey:@"FirstName"];

        [xmlString appendString:(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
    }


    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty) != NULL)
    {
        [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty) forKey:@"LastName"];

        [xmlString appendString:(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
    }

    [dictAddress setValue:xmlString forKey:@"Name"];

    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty) != NULL)
    {
        CFStringRef company = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
        if(company)
        {
            [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty) forKey:@"CompanyName"];
            CFRelease(company);
        }
    }

    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty) != NULL)
    {

        ABMultiValueRef phones =(__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));

        NSString* Str=@"";
        NSString* phoneLabel;

        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
        {
            phoneLabel = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);

            //if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Main>!$_"])
            if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
            {
                Str = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
                Str =[[Str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];




                [dictAddress setValue:Str forKey:@"PhoneHome"];
            }
            else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"])
            {
                Str = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                Str =[[Str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
                [dictAddress setValue:Str forKey:@"PhoneMobile"];
            }
            //else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Other>!$_"])
            else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
            {
                Str = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                Str =[[Str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
                [dictAddress setValue:Str forKey:@"PhoneWork"];
            }
        }
        CFRelease(phones);

    }


    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty) != NULL)
    {

        //Person address
        ABMultiValueRef addresses = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(addresses) != 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(addresses);i++)
            {
                CFStringRef address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addresses, i);


                NSString *StrCity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [(__bridge NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"City"]];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrCity forKey:@"AddressCity"];

                NSString *StrCountry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ (__bridge
                                                                            NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"Country"]];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrCountry forKey:@"AddressCountry"];

                NSString *StrState = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(__bridge NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"State"]];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrState forKey:@"AddressState"];

                NSString *StrCountryCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(__bridge NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"CountryCode"]];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrCountryCode forKey:@"AddressCountryCode"];

                NSString *StrStreet = (NSString*)[(__bridge NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"Street"];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrStreet forKey:@"AddressStreet"];

                NSString *StrZip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(__bridge NSDictionary*)address objectForKey:@"ZIP"]];
                [dictAddress setValue:StrZip forKey:@"AddressZipCode"];

            }

        }
        else
            CFRelease(addresses);
    }

    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty) != NULL)
    {
        //person email

        NSString* emailLabel;

        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) != 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);i++)
            {
                emailLabel = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, i);

                if ([emailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i)) forKey:@"EmailWork"];
                }
                else if([emailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i)) forKey:@"EmailHome"];
                }
                else if([emailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Other>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i)) forKey:@"EmailOther"];
                }
            }
        }
        else
            CFRelease(emails);
    }


    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty) != NULL)
    {
        NSString* URLLabel;

        ABMultiValueRef urls = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(urls) != 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(urls);i++)
            {
                URLLabel = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(urls, i);

                if ([URLLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(urls, i)) forKey:@"URLWork"];
                }
                else if([URLLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(urls, i)) forKey:@"URLHome"];
                }
                else if([URLLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Other>!$_"])
                {
                    [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge id)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(urls, i)) forKey:@"URLOther"];
                }

            }
        }

    }

    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty) != NULL)
    {
        [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty) forKey:@"Note"];
    }


    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonCreationDateProperty) != NULL)
    {
        [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonCreationDateProperty) forKey:@"CreationDate"];
    }


    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonModificationDateProperty) != NULL)
    {
        [dictAddress setValue:(__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonModificationDateProperty) forKey:@"ModificationDate"];
    }

    /*
     if (![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"EmailHome"] isEqualToString:@""] || ![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"EmailOther"] isEqualToString:@""] || ![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"EmailWork"] isEqualToString:@""])
     {
     dictAddress = nil;
     }*/

    NSLog(@"%@",dictAddress);

    NSMutableArray *numberDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneHome"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //    [numberDict setValue:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneHome"] forKey:@"PhoneHome"];
        [numberDict addObject:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneHome"]];
    }
    if (![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneMobile"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //    [numberDict setValue:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneMobile"] forKey:@"PhoneMobile"];
        [numberDict addObject:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneMobile"]];
    }
    if (![[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneWork"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [numberDict addObject:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneWork"]];
     //   [numberDict setValue:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"PhoneWork"] forKey:@"PhoneWork"];
    }
    [dictPhoneNumberFinal setObject:numberDict forKey:[dictAddress valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if (loadingView) {
        [loadingView removeView];
        loadingView = nil;
    }
});


// arrContactNames = [[dictPhoneNumberFinal allKeys] mutableCopy];

  arrContactNames =[[[dictPhoneNumberFinal allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] mutableCopy];




if(arrContactNames.count != 0)
{
    [tblView reloadData];
    //        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    //                [view setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
    //
    //        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //        [self.tableView addSubview:view];
    //        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    //        [self addPopOverViewWithTag:1 :arrContactNames];

}
else{
    [appDelegate userAlert:@"No contacts available."];
}
```

}

Comment: The question is about opening the Contacts app from within the application, not about accessing the contacts within the app.