# How to save a contact to Android/IOS phone book (contacts app) when a user clicks an html button on my website

Tags: android, html, ios, deep-linking, contacts

I am trying to make a website where a user can click a button or click a link and it opens the phone's native Contacts app and fills in provided information from the website. I spent my day doing research and couldn't find useful information. I found out the below line about Deep Links,  where I can put

```
<a href="instagram://user?username=instagram">Link</a>
```

and this opens the Instagram app on my phone. I am assuming I need something like this to open the Contacts app.

Comment: For iOS you may find what you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531585/is-there-a-custom-url-scheme-for-the-built-in-contacts-app)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we don't have any available deep link to open Contacts app. Apple provide the CNSaveRequest APIs to update/add/delete contact without using interface but I don't know anyway to access this API from website